# Has mongoose deprecated the connection() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mean

Which one is it? why do some mongoose code have `mongoose.connect()`, while others have `mongoose.connection()`

I feel like `connection()` method is the latest. It seems that `connect()` is deprecated.

Comment: [The docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) say *You can connect to MongoDB with the `mongoose.connect()` method.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose has pools of sockets that connect to mongodb which are called "connections". You can create connections with both `mongoose.connect()` and `mongoose.createConnection()`
None of them are deprecated and you can find them in [Mongoose Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect)

**Mongoose.connect():**

Creates default mongoose connection. It is helpful when you only want to have a single connection to db.

**Mongoose.createConnection():**

Creates a connection instance. Each connection instance maps to a single database. This method is helpful when managing multiple db connections.

You can see the comments on this Github issue too:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4700